# download a source code of web pages using curl php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download a source code of web pages using curl php code but its downloading only for few pages for rest pages file is empty.
 I googled it but im not getting solution.

My source code is :-

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'CURL via PHP');
$out = curl_exec($ch);
$fp = fopen('f1.html', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $out);
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
```

What options to add ? Where i am wrong ?
Pls help.

Comment: Did a quick search on curl, know nothing about it. But my first guess would be some sort of buffer size, does curl have a config of sorts.`CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE`

Comment: Hey!! thanks for your reply. And i tried everything..My code is working for few sites. I mean source code of those getting downloaded but for few file remains empty. I tried all options. I thought its because of large amount of content but then those files which are getting downloaded also have large amount of contents. So im not getting whats the issue.

Comment: [Somebody with similar issue- Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814149/curl-not-working-for-getting-a-web-page-content-why)

Comment: Ya but the problem he has is not same as mine im inputting proper url also i set followlocation=>true. But not getting resolved.

Comment: I set all options again. Now even when im inputting new url its downloading data of some old url only. Its behaving weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a user-agent that suggests you're a browser. Some servers will block curl/wget/etc.

For example: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22

Comment: $ch = curl_init();curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strurl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$out = curl_exec($ch);
$fp = fopen('f1.html', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $out);
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
Tried but same issue.Only few webpages are getting download.I guess code is fine.I don know what going wrong.Why not working for few And im running on stage without https still dont know.

Comment: Pastebin your full code and provide a problematic URL. I'll do some testing.

Comment: $url = $_POST['url']
$ch = curl_init()
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"")
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER ,true)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,120)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT ,120)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS ,10)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
$out = curl_exec($ch)
$fp = fopen('f1','w+')
fwrite($fp,$out)
fclose($fp)
curl_close($ch)

Comment: but not with http://blog.kyplex.com/2011/03/curl-wget-password-protected-pages.html or any other websites

Comment: Put the code at pastebin.com. SO's comment system isn't ideal.